# Given a right triangle's perimeter and difference between median and height to the hypotenuse, find it's area.

Tags: geometry, triangles

I have been trying to solve the following problem for a while:

You are given a right triangle ABC (angle C is right). The perimeter ABC is 72. CK is the median, and CM is the height to the hypotenuse. CK - CM = 7. Find the area of the triangle.

You can find a diagram [here](https://www.geogebra.org/m/qG4Et5rp?doneurl=%2Fgale%252Bstaneva).

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Hint: $m=\frac c2$.

Comment: I know, I have used it while trying to solve it

Comment: You have

$a+b+c=72$,

$\frac{c}{2}-\frac{ab}{c}=7$,

$a^2+b^2=c^2$, just solve the (system of) equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking @Frank000's suggestion to give a full answer for those that wish to see one possible method.

Using the fact that $$\displaystyle \frac{c}{2} - \frac{ab}{c} = 7$$ we rearrange to find 
$$
c^2 -14c = 2ab.
$$
Note also that $a+b=72-c$, squaring this gives $$ a^2 + 2ab + b^2 = 72^2 -144c +c^2,$$
since $a^2 + b^2 =c^2$ and we have an expression for $2ab$,
$$
c^2 + c^2 - 14c = 72^2 -144c +c^2,
$$
or rather
$$
c^2 + 130c - 72^2 = 0,
$$
the positive solution of which is $c=32$, giving $ a = \displaystyle \frac{288}{b}$,  and substitution into the pythagorean theorem gives $$\frac{288^2}{b^2} + b^2 = 32^2,$$ which gives $a = 4(5 \pm 7)$, $b = 4(5 \mp 7)$.

This problem could probably also be done with multiple applications of Heron's formula, summing the area of the some of the interior triangles.

Comment: Thank you so much for the full answer!